# Laravel mime type guessers alternative

Tags: php, laravel-5

My validation rules,

```
// Get request input
$caption = Request::input('caption');
$photo = Request::file('photo');

// Request validation
$validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'caption' => $caption,
            'photo' => $photo
        ],
        [
            'caption' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg'
        ]
    );

// If validation fails
if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Error!

> LogicException in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 127: Unable to guess the
>   mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the
>   php_fileinfo extension?)

I know the solution is to enable **extension=php_fileinfo.dll** in the php.ini settings.

But I am on a shared hosting and I have already talked to the server administrator to enable the extension. Unfortunately, they rejected my request showing some of the security reason.

Is their any alternative so I can validate my images?

Comment: show your code where u try to guess a mimetype

Comment: @M0rtiis please check my updated question, but it's not about the existing code that is not working, the fact is php_fileinfo.dll extension is not enabled in my hosts so "mimes:jpeg,jpg" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get mime type without `php_fileinfo.dll` **SAFELY**, ([mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php) - deprecated)

You can get it from file extension (using somthing like https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/utils/mimeTypes.php) and create your own validation rule. but its not safe.

Sad, but really helpfull advice will be to change a hoster.

Comment: BTW, hoster lies to you. php_fileinfo.dll have no connection to security. Mb it have connection with their laziness or competence